# updating an event by dragging/dropping fullcalendar- Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for a project I'm developing ... I have only one feature left to be implemented, which is when an existing event is dragged from it's original position to another time or date. I would like to know how I get the current object information (title, new start time, old start time, id, url, etc), so I can update the database with the newer information ... which property from the Fullcalendar object do I use?
I implemented the `drop` property;

```
    drop  : function(date, allDay) {
            // retrieve the dropped element's stored event object
            var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
            // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't 
            // have a reference object
            var copiedEventObject   = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);
            // assign it the date that was reported
            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event `sticks`
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

            // if the 'remove after drop' checkbox checked?
            if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                // if so remove the element from the "Draggable Events"
                $(this).remove();
            }
    },
```

but it's not doing what I wanted ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at the Event Dragging and Resizing http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/

I think what you are looking for the **eventDrop** callback.

> Triggered when dragging stops and the event has moved to a different
>   day/time.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventDrop/

Example from arshaw's site:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        // events here
    ],
    editable: true,
    eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revertFunc) {

        alert(
            event.title + " was moved " +
            dayDelta + " days and " +
            minuteDelta + " minutes."
        );

        if (allDay) {
            alert("Event is now all-day");
        }else{
            alert("Event has a time-of-day");
        }

        if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
            revertFunc();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, I think eventDrop() does not called when you are dragging external Event onto the Calendar. Instead drop() function. In My case, the external event drops into calendar (On Resource View) but it wont showing there, but when I change month and Week view, and the same external event showing. So I am confused that how I can bring the same on ResourceView.

Comment: Interesting @AffanPathan, can you add a fiddle here with your issue?

Comment: I have missed the resources[] properties, once I have fixed it, and now its working fine. :)