# how to read and save data from mysql to fullcalendar in this script?

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I want to save the evens changes to mysql, but I can not figure out how to post data to mysql in the script. This is the [demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33338943/fc/index.html). Anyone can make a sample please?

```
//actually cursor position
var currentMousePos = {
    x: -1,
    y: -1
};

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

   jQuery(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
        currentMousePos.x = event.pageX;
        currentMousePos.y = event.pageY;
    });

var testBlla = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"title":"Task 1.2","start":"2013-08-04","end":"2013-08-06","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(72, 61, 139)","mandays":"3"},{"title":"Task 2.2","start":"2013-08-08","end":"2013-08-12","allDay":true,"resource":"mapl","backgroundColor":"rgb(34, 139, 34)","mandays":"5"},{"title":"Task 3.2","start":"2013-08-11","end":"2013-08-18","allDay":true,"resource":"zone","backgroundColor":"rgb(0, 139, 139)","mandays":"8"},{"title":"Task 4.3","start":"2013-08-11","end":"2013-08-23","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(178, 34, 34)","mandays":"13"},{"title":"Task 4.4","start":"2013-08-12","end":"2014-08-25","allDay":true,"resource":"mamu","backgroundColor":"rgb(178, 34, 34)","mandays":"14"},{"title":"Task 4.5","start":"2013-08-15","end":"2013-08-29","allDay":true,"resource":"mapl","backgroundColor":"rgb(178, 34, 34)","mandays":"15"},{"title":"Task 4.6","start":"2013-08-19","end":"2013-08-03","allDay":true,"resource":"zone","backgroundColor":"rgb(178, 34, 34)","mandays":"16"},{"title":"Task 4.3","start":"2013-08-08","end":"2013-08-20","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(178, 34, 34)","mandays":"13"},{"title":"Task 3.2","start":"2013-08-12","end":"2013-08-19","allDay":true,"resource":"mamu","backgroundColor":"rgb(0, 139, 139)","mandays":"8"},{"title":"Task 2.3","start":"2013-08-13","end":"2013-08-15","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(34, 139, 34)","mandays":"3"},{"title":"Task 2.5","start":"2013-08-17","end":"2013-08-27","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(34, 139, 34)","mandays":"11"},{"title":"Task 2.8","start":"2013-08-08","end":"2013-08-14","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(34, 139, 34)","mandays":"7"},{"title":"Task 1.9","start":"2013-08-20","end":"2013-08-28","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(72, 61, 139)","mandays":"9"},{"title":"Task 1.9","start":"2013-08-16","end":"2013-08-24","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(72, 61, 139)","mandays":"9"},{"title":"Task 1.10","start":"2013-08-12","end":"2013-08-13","allDay":true,"resource":"jusa","backgroundColor":"rgb(72, 61, 139)","mandays":"2"}]');

var testBRe = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"id":"mapl","name":"Martin"},{"id":"zone","name":"Zora"},{"id":"jusa","name":"Julius"},{"id":"mamu","name":"Marcel"},{"id":"mami","name":"Marian"},{"id":"jahr","name":"Jan"},{"id":"peli","name":"Peter"}]');

    jQuery("td[name=role]").each(function (i, roleEl) {
        var rColor = getRandomColor(i);
        jQuery(roleEl).parent().find(".external-event").each(function (j, taskEl) {
            jQuery(taskEl).css("background-color", rColor);
            jQuery(taskEl).parent().css("background-color", rColor);
            jQuery(taskEl).next().css("background-color", rColor);
        });
    });

    jQuery('#external-events div.external-event').each(function () {

        // create an Event Object (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)
        // it doesn't need to have a start or end
        var eventObject = {
            title: jQuery.trim(jQuery(this).text()),
            mandays: jQuery(this).next().text(),
            backgroundColor: jQuery(this).css("background-color"),
            color: jQuery(this).css("background-color"),
            className: "task-in-call"
        };

        // store the Event Object in the DOM element so we can get to it later
        jQuery(this).data('eventObject', eventObject);

        // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
        jQuery(this).draggable({
            zIndex: 999,
            revert: true, // will cause the event to go back to its
            revertDuration: 0 //  original position after the drag
        });

    });

    var calendar = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar({

        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,resourceDay,resourceWeek,resourceMonth, Save '
        },

        titleFormat: {
            resourceMonth: 'MMM yyyy',
        },
        columnFormat: {
            month: 'dddd',
            week: 'ddd d.M.',
            day: 'dddd d.M.',
            resourceDay: 'HH:mm',
            resourceMonth: 'd.M.',
            resourceWeek: 'dddd d.M.',
            resourceNextWeeks: 'dddd d.M.'
        },

        firstDay: 1,
        defaultView: "resourceMonth",
        //events: "events.php",//读取数据库sample
        editable: true,
        dragRevertDuration: 0,
        droppable: true,
        drop: function (date, allDay, ev, ui, resource) { // this function is called when something is dropped

            var originalEventObject = jQuery(this).data('eventObject');
            var copiedEventObject = jQuery.extend({}, originalEventObject);

            copiedEventObject.resource = resource.id;

            var startDate = new Date(date);
            startDate.setHours(0);
            startDate.setMinutes(0);
            startDate.setSeconds(0);
            startDate.setMilliseconds(0);

            copiedEventObject.start = date;
            var endDate = new Date(date);
            endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + parseInt(originalEventObject.mandays) - 1);
            endDate.setHours(0);
            endDate.setMinutes(0);
            endDate.setSeconds(0);
            endDate.setMilliseconds(0);
            copiedEventObject.end = endDate;

            copiedEventObject.mandays = originalEventObject.mandays;
             copiedEventObject.id = (resource.id + "-" + copiedEventObject.title).replace(" ", "") + "_-_" +
                new Date().getTime();

                console.log("tu nacitane: " + copiedEventObject.id);

            // render the event on the calendar
            // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
            if (checkEvent(copiedEventObject)) {

               jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);
                jQuery("#message").text('dragged');
//
//                if (jQuery('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
//                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
//                    var bgcolor = jQuery(this).css("background-color");
//                    jQuery(this).removeAttr("style");
//                    jQuery(this).addClass("movedTask");
//                    jQuery(this).css("background-color", bgcolor);
//                }
            }

        },
        selectable: true,
        minTime: 8,
        maxTime: 16,
        selectHelper: true,
        resources: testBRe,
        //events: testBlla,
        resourceRender: function (resource, element, view) {
            // this is triggered when the resource is rendered, just like eventRender
        },
    eventMouseover: function (event, jsEvent) {
        jQuery(this).mousemove(function (e) {
        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
        if (isElemOverDiv()) {
            if (!trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
                trashEl.addClass("to-trash");
            }
        } else {
            if (trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
                trashEl.removeClass("to-trash");
            }

        }
        });
    },
    eventDragStop: function (event, jsEvent, ui, view) {
        if (isElemOverDiv()) {
        console.log("removing " + event.id);
        jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event.id);

        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');
        if (trashEl.hasClass("to-trash")) {
            trashEl.removeClass("to-trash");
        }
        } else {
            console.log("not in trash");
        }
    },
    loading: function (bool) {
        console.log("test");
        if (!bool) {
        jQuery('.fc-header-left').append('<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="/images/cal-trash.png"></img></div>');

        }
    },  
        eventResize: function (event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view) {
            jQuery("#message").text('event was resized, new endtime: ' + event.end);
        },
        eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

        }
    });


    jQuery("#forTest").on("click", function(e){
        getEvents();
    });

jQuery('.fc-header-left').append('<div id="calendarTrash" class="calendar-trash"><img src="images/cal-trash.png"></img></div>');
});

function checkEvent(newEvent) {
    var allEvents = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var len = allEvents == null ? 0 : allEvents.length;
    var newStart = newEvent.start.getTime();
    var newMandays = newEvent.mandays
    var newTaskName = newEvent.title;
    var newResourceId = newEvent.resource;


    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (newEvent != allEvents[i]) {
            var evStart = allEvents[i].start.getTime();
            var evMandays = allEvents[i].mandays;
            var evTaskName = allEvents[i].title;
            var evResourceId = allEvents[i].resource;
            console.log("data: " + allEvents[i].mandays);

            if (newStart == evStart && newMandays == evMandays && evTaskName == newTaskName && evResourceId == newResourceId) {
                jQuery("#message").text("Cant drag this task: task exist");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function getEvents() {
    var allEvents = jQuery('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
    var len = allEvents == null ? 0 : allEvents.length;
    var result = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {

    var title = allEvents[i].title;
    var start = jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(allEvents[i].start, "yyyy-MM-dd");
    var end = allEvents[i].end != null ? jQuery.fullCalendar.formatDate(allEvents[i].end, "yyyy-MM-dd") : start;
    var allDay = allEvents[i].allDay;
    var resource = allEvents[i].resource[0];
    var backgroundColor = allEvents[i].backgroundColor;
    var textColor = allEvents[i].textColor;
    var mandays = allEvents[i].mandays;

        var jEvent = {
            title: title,
            start: start,
            end: end,
            allDay: allDay,
            resource: resource,
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
            textColor: textColor,
            mandays: mandays
        }
        result.push(jEvent);
    }
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
}


function getRandomColor(index) {
    //    var letters = '23456789ABCD'.split('');
    //    var color = '#';
    //    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    //        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 12)];
    //    }
    var color = new Array("#483D8B", "#228B22", "#008B8B", "#B22222");
    return color[index];
}

//check if cursor is in trash 
    function isElemOverDiv() {
        var trashEl = jQuery('#calendarTrash');

        var ofs = trashEl.offset();

        var x1 = ofs.left;
        var x2 = ofs.left + trashEl.outerWidth(true);
        var y1 = ofs.top;
        var y2 = ofs.top + trashEl.outerHeight(true);

        if (currentMousePos.x >= x1 && currentMousePos.x <= x2 &&
            currentMousePos.y >= y1 && currentMousePos.y <= y2) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }`
```

this is my php file

```
<?php

$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$resource = $_POST['resource'];
$backgroundcolor = $_POST['bacgroundcolor'];
$mandays = $_POST['mandays'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=local;dbname=fullcalendar', 'root', 'root');
$bdd->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// update the records
$sql = "update lot_evenement set title=:title, start=:start, end=:end, url=:url, resource=:resource, backgroundcolor =:backgroundcolor, manday=:manday  where id='$id'";

$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end,  ':url'=>$url, ':resource'=>$resource, ':backgroundcolor'=>$backgroundcolor, ':manday'=>$manday));

?>
```

This is my database script..

```
 CREATE TABLE lot_evenement (
  'id' int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  'title' varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  'start' datetime NOT NULL,
  'end' datetime default NULL,
  'url' varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  'allDay' varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default 'false',
  'resource' varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  'backgroundcolor' varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  'mandays' int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  ('id')
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=22 ;
```

--

### -- 'lot_evenement'

```
INSERT INTO 'lot_evenement' VALUES (4, 0x5461736b20342e33, '2014-04-27 22:12:34', '2014-04-30 22:12:41', '', 0x66616c7365, '4', 'rgb(178, 34, 34)', 4);
INSERT INTO `lot_evenement` VALUES (3, 0x5461736b20332e32, '2014-04-13 22:10:15', '2014-04-15 22:10:24', '', 0x66616c7365, '4', 'rgb(0, 139, 139)', 3);
INSERT INTO `lot_evenement` VALUES (2, 0x5461736b20322e32, '2014-04-23 22:09:00', '2014-04-23 22:09:07', '', 0x66616c7365, '2', 'rgb(34, 139, 34)', 1);
INSERT INTO `lot_evenement` VALUES (1, 0x5461736b20312e32, '2014-04-15 22:07:20', '2014-04-18 22:07:31', '', 0x66616c7365, '1', 'rgb(72, 61, 139)', 3);
```

Comment: Where is your backend PHP code (if any)?

Comment: I could be overlooking it but I'm not seeing the AJAX call to update the event when it is dragged to another time slot etc.

Using JSfiddle.net or something similar can you show me what you currently have working? 

I'm assuming you have another PHP script that allows you to read/load the events and has JSON output.

Comment: That is why I am asking here, I don't know AJAX at all :(

Comment: You're on the right track. However, I get the feeling you're wanting drag and drop events to trigger an update. [Drag and Drop with Fullcalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434303/updating-an-event-by-dragging-dropping-fullcalendar-javascript)

You'll need the following:
1. Detect when the drag event is over
2. Learn how to make an AJAX request with JQuery
3. Make an AJAX call to call your PHP script. It should look something like http://localhost/script.php?id=1&title=Blah&start=13349835&url=blah.com&end=14403439

Comment: [Learning Ajax](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery--net-6289)