# Drag and drop external elements in FullCalendar - With Resource Day View

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In my project I am using Sean Kenny's fullCalendar plugin, https://github.com/seankenny/fullcalendar/blob/v2/dist/fullcalendar.js. I am using the defaultView: 'resourceDay'. I wants to drag and drop external elements in to the calendar. It is working fine with other views like defaultView: 'agendaDay', but not with defaultView: 'resourceDay'. Is it possible to drag and drop the external element into the calendar with resourceDay view?

The following is the sample I tried,

```
     $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         header: {
             left: 'prev,next today',
             center: 'title',
             right: 'month,agendaWeek,resourceDay'
         },             
         defaultView: 'resourceDay',                      
         defaultDate: $.fullCalendar.moment( new Date(sessionStorage.sDate) ),              
         editable: true,
         droppable: true,            
         minTime: '07:00:00', 
         maxTime: '22:00:00',
         slotDuration: '00:05:00',
         axisFormat: 'h(:mm) A',               
         nowIndicator: true,
         resources: [{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzAAI","name":"some name"},{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzAAP","name":"some name"},{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzABP","name":"some name"},{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzABA","name":"some name"}],
         events:[{
         appointmentId: "xxxxxxxxx",
         appointmentTreatmentId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         className: "scheduled",
         doctorName: "some name",
         employee: "xx-xxxx",
         employeeId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",             
         isNew: false,
         location: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         mobile: "(xxx) xxx-xxxx",
         notes: "sample notes",
         orderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         patient: "some patient",
         patientId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
         resources: "xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzAAI",            
         },
         {
         appointmentId: "xxxxxxxxx",
         appointmentTreatmentId: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
         className: "scheduled",
         doctorName: "some name",
         employee: "xx-xxxx",
         employeeId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",             
         isNew: false,
         location: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         mobile: "(xxx) xxx-xxxx",
         notes: "sample notes",
         orderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         patient: "some patient",
         patientId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
         resources: "xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzAAP"             
         },
         {
         appointmentId: "xxxxxxxxx",
         appointmentTreatmentId: "xxxxxxxx9AAA",
         className: "scheduled",
         doctorName: "some name",
         employee: "xx-xxxx",
         employeeId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
         isNew: false,
         location: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         mobile: "(xxx) xxx-xxxx",
         notes: "sample notes",
         orderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         patient: "some patient",
         patientId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
         resources: "xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzABP"
         },
         {
         appointmentId: "xxxxxxxxx",
         appointmentTreatmentId: "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
         className: "scheduled",
         doctorName: "some name",
         employee: "xx-xxxx",
         employeeId: "xxxxxxxxxxx"
         isNew: false,
         location: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         mobile: "(xxx) xxx-xxxx",
         notes: "sample notes",
         orderId: "xxxxxxxxxx",
         patient: "some patient",
         patientId: "xxxxxxxxxxx",
         resources: "xxxxxxxxxxxx7PzABA"
         }
         ], 
         viewDisplay: function(view) {   
             window.clearInterval(timelineInterval);
             timelineInterval = window.setInterval(setTimeline, 10000);

         },                    
         selectable: {
             month: false,
             default: true
         },              
         select: function(start, end, ev) {
             setTheDocValue(ev.data.id, (start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), (end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'), '', '');
         },

         drop: function(date, ev) {                    
                 var oEventObject = $(this).data('event');
                 var cEventObject = $.extend({}, oEventObject);                    
                 cEventObject.start = date;                     
                 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', cEventObject, true);

         }, 
        eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui) { 

         }                       
     });
```

Please help me.
Thanks

Comment: Infact, it's us who should ask you to share the sample code you have tried...not the other way around

Comment: My be this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434303/updating-an-event-by-dragging-dropping-fullcalendar-javascript is helpfull for you

Comment: @Console.log I tried with the eventDrop property also. But it is not working. The eventDrop property gets fired when I drag and drop an event which is already present in the calendar, but not when dragging and dropping external element into the calendar

Comment: @JohncyBinoy , have you get resolved this issue?

Comment: In My case, the external event drops into calendar (I am trying to drop it on Resource View) but it wont showing there (Just disappear), but when I change month and Week view, and the same external dropped event showing!!! So I am confused that how I can bring the same on ResourceView. Whe the dropped event does not stick to ResrouceView, even I have set the resourceId with the event too.

Comment: I have solved the same, using following code:
//Reading External Events, assigned them resources[] property
var eventObject = {
    title: jq.trim(jq(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
    resources: ["0"]
   };

while in drop: function () event, did following code:
drop: function(date, ev) {                    
                 var oEventObject = $(this).data('event');
                 var cEventObject = $.extend({}, oEventObject);                    
                 cEventObject.start = date;
  cEventObject.resources = ["<your resourceID>"];

Done!